# google custom search api: combining values for the 'rights' parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apis-explorer

I have created a `node.js` web app with the npm `'google-images'` package to connect to google's `custom-search-api` to fetch image URLs.

In the package's search-options I want to set the `'rights'` parameter such that only URLs for images tagged for `'commercial'` use are returned, but there is no single value for that param to achieve this `(cc_publicdomain, cc_attribute, cc_sharealike, cc_noncommercial, cc_nonderived)`.

I expect I have to combine some of the values above, but how can this be done through from within the package's options?

Below are the package's options as I am currently using them:

```js
const searchSettings = {
  c2coff: '1',
  fileType: 'jpg ',
  imgSize: 'huge',
  imgType: 'photo',
  linkSite: 'yes',
  lr: 'lang_en',
  rights: '!cc_noncommercial',
  safe: 'high',
  searchType: 'image',
  siteSearch: 'https://www.facebook.com/',
  siteSearchFilter: 'e'
}
```